# How to debug Angular's generated code

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am trying to trace something down and I've hit a dead end/brick wall. I'm using the latest Chrome(51.0.2704.84) and angular.js (1.4.2) with angular-smart-table (2.0.3) and I can't debug a problem because I can't see the source.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is angular or smarttable .. either way it's a real nuisance since I can't see into `top.txt` or `bottom.txt`. Any way I can see the generated code?

Comment: have you tried using the full source, i.e. `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` for each of your scripts?

Comment: @Claies yup, nothing is minified, first thing i checked.

Comment: *something* is minified; your callstack has `t`, `r`, `n`......

Comment: @Claies i just went through the code and you're right there was a jquery file being minified and thats what you see there, but as a whole everything else is not. I've moved to the full source version and still nothing, i still see the damn bottom.txt/top.txt files with nothing in them.